# Scrollbar appears in Chrome but there is nothing to scroll

Tags: css, scroll

I'm posting this again because I cannot login to my old account. I am using a template for a small portfolio webpage. The problem is that when the website is opened in Chrome, a scrollbar always appears on the main page as shown below:

i.stack.imgur.com/rCB3m.jpg

This does not happen in Firefox, Edge and IE. [Here](https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/dimension/) is a link to the demo of the template and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mxspdw92/1/) a fiddle with the CSS. Both display the unnecessary scrollbar when Chrome is used. I have tried the following things:

adding this line to the html file but it didn't help:

```
.content {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

adding this line, but it hides the scrollbar not only on the main page but also on all subpages.

```
body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I also removed parts of the CSS code in order to find out what causes the problem. The scrollbar disappears when I remove this part of the script but I cannot figure out a way to fix the issue:

```
#wrapper {
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        -moz-flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -moz-align-items: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -moz-justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4rem 2rem;
        z-index: 3;
    }

        #wrapper:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
        }
```

I hope that you guys can help me out here.

Best,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```css
#wrapper:before { 
  content: ''; 
  display: block
}
```

... from your `CSS` to fix the scrollbar issue.

And to keep your contents vertically centered, change `#wrapper`'s `justify-content` from `space-between` to `center`:

```css
#wrapper {
  /* ... */
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -moz-justify-content: center;
      -ms-justify-content: center;
          justify-content: center;
  /* ... */
}
```

Updated [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/xzbwzayL/1/).

Comment: @JayDan It is both bad etiquette and ineffective to ask new questions in comments on existing questions or answers. It's much better to post a new question, as it is most likely to also help future visitors with a similar issue. That's how [so] works. And, as a side note, if you can't login to your old account, there are plenty of ways to recover it. Creating a new one is not the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the min-height to 100 viewport height, which is the height of the screen you're viewing on, and adding padding to that. Try changing to 98vh instead.